# How to format data after select Datepicker Material?

Tags: angular

I use datepicker from Angualr material with reactive form:

```
<mat-form-field >
  <mat-label>Начальная дата...</mat-label>
  <input formControlName="start" matInput [matDatepicker]="dateOrderDgeStart" />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateOrderDgeStart"> </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dateOrderDgeStart></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

This datepicker is connected to reactive form using control: `formControlName="start"`.

When user selects value the form control `formGrop.control["start"]` accepts value: `Thu Jul 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Voronej Standard Time)`.

Problem is I have over 20 the same datepickers and I dont want to catch change event in each component like this:

```
(dateChange)="changeEvent('change', $event)"

changeEvent(type: string, event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    console.log(event.value);
}
```

Instead that I iterate all elements of form (controls) and do transformation of values:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(formGroup)) {
   if (key == 'date1' || key == 'date2' || key == 'date3') {
        // Format date here
   }
```

But I dont like this too, because I have over 50 datepickers and it look dummy:

`if (key == 'date1' ...`
}

How to solve this and fromat only datepickers to value `mm.dd.yyyy` ?

It would be create if possible to check by type, like this:

```
if (control.type === 'date') {
   // Make values chnages
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not try to make another loop for the datepicker count

```
let datePickerCount = 50;
for (const key of Object.keys(formGroup)) {
   for(let i = 1; i <= datePickerCount ; i++){
     if (key == 'date'+i) {
        somedate+i = formatDate(new Date(event), "MM/dd/yyyy", "en-US")
     }
   }
```

don't forget to import formatDate

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
```

Answer (score 0):

use MAT_DATE_FORMATS to change the fromat

```
    const APP_DATE_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
      parse: {
         dateInput: 'LL',
      },
     display: {
       dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
       monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
       dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
       monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY'
     }
   };
```

And add it to the provider of module

```
{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: APP_DATE_FORMATS },
```

Comment: But it changes in visible part (display data), but I need change only data(value) to make server request,